# Python relative imports using setuptools with scripts

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, package

I am transitioning to a package-based workflow for a project I've been working on. I want to be able to separate development and production environments and I think setuptools offers this possibility with some degree of ease.

I have a project structured as follows:

```
modulename/
    setup.py
    modulename/
         file_a.py
         script.py
```

In script.py, I want to import file_a.py. Currently I do this by doing `import file_a`.

My setup.py looks like:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(name='modulename',
  packages = find_packages(),
  package_dir = {'': '../modulename'},
  scripts = ['modulename/script.py'])
```

Currently, when I run `script.py` after doing `python setup.py install`, I get an error message:

`SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import`

I have tried a variety of permutations of `package_dir = ...`, most notably `package_dir = {'': 'modulename'}`, but this throws another error on install, `error: package directory 'modulename/modulename' does not exist`

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. The documentation online for setuptools is relatively poor in dealing with situations involving relative imports. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I guess the problem is not the `setup.py`, but `script.py` running as the `__main__` module and using relative import at the same time. Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3)

Comment: Okay, so is the move here to keep the script outside of the package and then just use normal imports?

Comment: That's basically it, I suppose.

Comment: Do you want to post an actual answer and I'll accept it, since this functionally solved my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not related with `setuptools`. Using relative imports inside the module being executed as `__main__` does not work out of the box. There are workarounds / hacks, but the most common solutions seems to be moving the script out of the package or using absolute imports in the script file.

Take a look at [Relative imports in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3) for the full story.